# chmod will not set directory permissions for user

Tags: macos, permissions, file-permissions, chmod

I am trying to learn UNIX permissions for the purposes of safeguarding raw data. My OS is macOS Catalina.

While trying to learn to use `chmod`, I've come across a situation where `chmod` will not make the changes I'm telling it to. Here is an `ls -lO@` of the folder I'm trying to change:

```
[~/Desktop/test--file-permissions]
> ls -lO@
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@ 4 leo  staff  - 128 Jul  4 16:11 test--work
    com.apple.favorite-rank.number#PS    14
    com.apple.macl   72
    com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags  42
```

I want to make this folder and all its contents read only:

```
chmod -R 444 test--work
```

If I do `ls -lO@` again, it shows that only permissions for the 'group' and 'other' have been set to read only but the 'user' permissions have remained the same:

```
[~/Desktop/test--file-permissions]
> ls -lO@
total 0
drwxr--r--@ 4 leo  staff  - 128 Jul  4 16:11 test--work
    com.apple.favorite-rank.number#PS    14
    com.apple.macl   72
    com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags  42
```

Why does `chmod` not change the user permissions? (I am using zsh, not bash, if that somehow affects anything)

Edit: The reason I'm trying to remove all write permissions, even for the user, is that my goal is to lock and protect raw scientific data on an external hard drive so that whoever plugs it into their computer to use (i.e. irrespective of 'user'), the files cannot be accidentally deleted or moved.

Edit 2: I found this on another post which suggests the access control list (ACL) might have something to do with it, but I don't know how that works: https://superuser.com/a/671456/945371

Edit 3: clarified by adding output of `ls -lO@` instead of just `ls -l`

Comment: ACLs shouldn't affect this (unless they forbid you from changing permissions entirely on the file). Did the `chmod` command print any error messages? The "`@`" in the listing indicates that the file has additional properties that `ls -l` doesn't show. Try `ls -leO@` instead, and edit the result into your question. Oh, and permissions on external volumes are a bit weird (different from those on internal volumes), and depend on what format the volume is in, so your tests may not be entirely relevant.

Comment: Permissions are ignored on non-boot drives with a mere checkbox in Get Info. Try setting the locked flag instead - https://superuser.com/questions/40749/command-to-unlock-locked-files-on-os-x

Comment: @gordon `chmod` did not throw any error. I've updated the post with output from `ls -lO@` instead of just `ls -l`.

Comment: @FoxDie Please add an `e` to that option list (`ls -leO@`) to get it to show any ACLs (just in case I'm wrong about them interfering somehow).